# How can i display one specific resource make available on every date in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

```
  resources: [{
      id: 'pending',
      title: 'Pending'
    },
    {
      id: 'delivery',
      title: 'Delivery Person'
    }
  ],
  events: [{
      start: '10:00',
      end: '14:00',
      id: "22218",
      daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      resourceId: "pending"
    },
    {
      startTime: "2022-10-19 14:00:00",
      endTime: "2022-10-20 16:00:00",
      id: "22219",
      resourceId: "delivery"
    }
  ]
```

In fullcalender v4 I'm having resources and events object like this.
What I want is, to repeat the pending order for every day on the given timeslot.

Could someone please help me with this?

Comment: Without a screenshot and/or some example of the sample event data and the expected outcome, it's a little difficult to be certain precisely what you mean. But are you looking for [recurring events](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/recurring-events), perhaps? It sounds like you have an event scheduled on a specific day and you actually want it to repeat every day until some date in the future? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74125118/how-to-make-a-repeated-resources-in-fullcalender](Question URL) here I posted the sample event data. Could you please refer it?
Thank you

Comment: No, you must post the code _here_, because 1) in order to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) a question must be self-contained with all relevant info shown within it, and 2) in order to be [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) a question must not be a duplicate of another question, so you can't ask the same thing twice. You must [edit] this question instead of posting multiple versions of your question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, My bad i couldn't able to find the way to edit this question. So i created another one. But now with the edit link , now updated the question..Thank you for addressing this.

Comment: No worries. For future reference, every question has an "edit" button at the bottom of it, just below the little blue tags :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see you seem to have got a bit confused with when you need the `startTime`/`endTime` or `start`/`end` properties, which are used for recurring and non-recurring events (respectively).

1. Your "pending" event, if you want it to recur, needs to use `startTime` and `endTime` [as per the recurring events documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/recurring-events), providing the values as times/durations. You can also, optionally, specify `startRecur` and `endRecur` to set the dates between which the recurrence will apply.
2. Your "delivery" event doesn't recur, but it also doesn't show up at all because you've used `startTime` and `endTime` as if it was recurring. Non-recurring events need `start` and `end` properties - again [as per the event parsing documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-parsing).

I think this is probably close to what you were intending. It wasn't clear when exactly you want the recurrence to start and end so I omitted that - you can easily add it:

```
events: [
      {
        startTime: "10:00",
        endTime: "14:00",
        id: "22218",
        daysOfWeek: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
        resourceId: "pending"
      },
      {
        start: "2022-10-19 14:00:00",
        end: "2022-10-20 16:00:00",
        id: "22219",
        resourceId: "delivery"
      }
    ]
```

Demos:

- Initial version using your code: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/NWMZavP
- Fixed version using my changes: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/VwxJrLJ